# Is Freestyle Line Priority broken?

Tags: color, freestyle

I can't seem to get the freestyle line priority in the material properties tab to work. The color is always the same as the base color set in the view layer properties.

Here is the intended way for it to work: https://freestyleintegration.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/line-color-priority/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid. I forgot to add a material modifier.

Comment: UV for stupidity :D